# How to check numerically that a dataset follows normal distribution with a mean and a covariance matrix? mean, cov matrix are known. (multivariate)?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have a dataset, I have found theoretically that the dataset follows a normal distribution with some mean and covariance matrix, (multivariate). Now I want a numerical verification of my theoretical result. How will I proceed? I have read articles related to Mardia test, chi-square goodness of fit test for a multivariate case but those tests show whether it is normally distributed or not but I want to check the normality test along with the particular mean and covariance matrix(which I derived theoretically)

Comment: A $T^2$ test may be in order. A $T^2$ pivot (a statistic since you said mean and covariance are given) constructed from multivariate normal observations is exactly a multiple of an $F$ random variable, which should be easily googled.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests describes several different tests.